# Generating rtf report Genexus web

Tags: rtf, genexus

I'm working with the Genexus platform and I'm trying to generate a report in rtf format (I need it with images and text, not just text). I am trying using the parameter for procedure `output_file()` and calling it as Http but from what I can see it is not working.

Does someone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to explain better which version, upgrades, and language you've been using because it can help others.

Anyway, i don't think that rtf is implemented in http protocol.

You may try to generate it as a file and do another procedure to download it.

**Edit:**

The output_file is used to name a file and a format for it:

Output_file() is used to name a file name and a standard for it:

*Syntax*

**Output_File**({ *name | att | &var*}, format);

**Where**:

*name | att | &var*

```
  Is the output name. In the case of output to a file, it is possible to indicate the path of the file to be generated, which must exist. It can also be a variable or an attribute, in which case its type must be Character.
```

*format*

```
  Is the output file format. Possible values are ‘GXR’, ‘RTF’, ‘XML’ ‘PDF’ or ‘TXT’ (the last one only for reports in text mode). It is ignored in the case of output through screen or printer.
```

You may still use it, whilst set the report as not main (Property Main = 'false') This should make it generate the rtf to the file name set in the output_file rule.

You must also set the Output property to "Only to file":

Ask User    The user will be asked where to send the output at execution time. This value only applies to Windows environments. This is the default value.

Only to File    The output is sent directly to a file. By default, the generated file has GXRPTn.GXR name (where n is a number starting at 0 and increasing when other open documents exist), except in the case that other name and/or format has been specified using the Output_File rule.

Only to Printer     The output is sent directly to the printer. (See Output Device Location Property below).
Only to Screen  The output is sent directly to the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using Genexus X Ev2 U4, generating in c#. I don't get how to do it as procedure with output_files can be called only with http protocol. Can you tell me something more?

Comment: Sure, did it above, in the original answer

Comment: Thanks Sandro, I'm going to try today and I'll let you know if it works for me

Comment: I'm trying and it's almost working. I stil have a problem, I'm doing this way: source: print layout: the printblock with a text and an image rules: output_file("F:\Model_GenexusX\GxwkbXEv2\Mars_Ev2_U4\CSharpModel\web\FILE\prova_NOimmagine.rtf","RTF");

It starts working but the generated file is empty and the procedure remains pending. Removing the image it works and stop being pending but the rtf generated is corrupted, when I open it in word or tetxpad i see for example:

{\rtf1\ansi {\fonttbl}\psz256\par \pagebb }

Thank you for your big help, very appreciated

Diego

Comment: You must only use a file name, not a complete path using output_file(), for instance:

output_file('report.rtf','rtf');

Glad that it helped, any upvote is appreciated :)

Comment: Unfortunately using just the name it doesn't generate anything, using the path I have the file corrupted...